# How to prompt user input in C++

Tags: c++

Why does my code only allow me to input first_name and then the program stops?

```
#include <iostream>


void employee_data(double &first_name, double &last_name, double &hours, double &hourly_rate);


int main()
{
    double first_name,
        last_name,
        hours,
        hourly_rate;

    employee_data(first_name, last_name, hours, hourly_rate);

}

//
// An input module that gathers employee data. 
//
void employee_data(double &first_name, double &last_name, double &hours, double &hourly_rate)
{
    std::cout << "Enter employee's first name: ";
    std::cin >> first_name;

    std::cout << "Enter employee's last name: ";
    std::cin >> last_name;

    std::cout << "Enter number of hours worked: ";
    std::cin >> hours;

    std::cout << "Enter hourly pay rate: ";
    std::cin >> hourly_rate;

}
```

When I run the program it shows up like this:

`Enter employee's first name: Ivan
Enter employee's last name: Enter number of hours worked: Enter hourly pay rate:
C:\Users\ivanc\source\repos\Project3\Debug\Project3.exe (process 4992) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .`

Why is it not prompting the user to input the different values?

Comment: Why did you choose `double` to represent names?

Comment: why is your first_name a double?

Comment: change data type to string for reading names or to make this code work, type number for the input you will see the next prompt will appear, you can realize the behavior yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If stream extraction fails, the stream enters an error state and all subsequent extractions automatically fail without doing anything.

Since you decided to represent your names as `double`s, reading `first_name` fails if you don't enter a number.

A more natural way to represent names would be `std::string`.